# CSS - making left div go over right div as an overlay on small screens

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I am using zurb foundation in my project and I have a layout with 2 divs in a row.  One takes up 4 columns on the left and the other takes up 8 columns on the right. On the left I have some content and on the right I have an image that takes up the whole div.
I would like on small screens to have the content of the left div go on top of the image, like an overlay, instead of right div going below the left div. But I am not sure how and what is the best way to achieve that?

```
<div class="header row">
    <div class="large-12 columns frontpage-header-content">
        <div class="large-4 columns frontpage-header-content-div">
            <div class="snirky-snark-box">
                <h3>Vi arbeider med å bygge kompetanse, spre kunnskap og positiv energi</h3>
                <div class="border"></div>
                <div class="payment-box">
                    <label for="support" id="payment-input"><span>Gi et beløp</span>
                        <input type="text" id="support">
                    </label>
                    <button type="button" class="button button-full" id="payment-button">Støtt oss</button>
                    <div class="payment-methods">
                        <p><span><img id="vipps" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/vipps.svg"></span><span>Bankkort</span><span>Sms</span><span>Faktura</span></p>
                    </div>
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="large-8 columns frontpage-header-image-div">
            <div class="frontpage-bg-image-wrapper">
                <div class="header-bg-image frontpage-header-hero"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/sfk-bg.png"></div>
                <div class="overlay"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php get_template_part('title-bar'); ?>
</div><!-- /.header -->


<div class="promo row">
</div>
```

I have managed to achieve with a following css that a left div goes over the right one as an overlay, but I have a problem with a `promo row`, since now the content of the promo row goes over the header as well, how can I push the promo row to go below the header?

```
@include breakpoint(medium down) {
  .frontpage-header-image, .frontpage-bg-image-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .frontpage-header-content, .singlepage-header-content {
    padding-top: 84px!important;
    position: relative;
  }

  .frontpage-header-content-div, .frontpage-header-image-div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 84px;
    padding: 0;
  }

  .snirky-snark-box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 22%;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;

    h3 {
      width: 200px;
      font-size: 24px;
    }
  }

  .snirky-snark-box .payment-box {
    padding: 0;
  }

  .payment-methods, .border {
    display: none!important;
  }

  .header > .columns {
    padding: 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than moving the divs around; how about duplicating the image as a background?

Add the class `show-for-medium` to `.frontpage-header-image-div`, this only shows the div if screen size > medium ([docs](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/visibility.html#show-by-screen-size)) and add something like this in your (s)css:

```
.frontpage-header-content {
    @include breakpoint(medium down) {
        background-image: url([your image url]);
        -webkit-background-size: contain;
        -moz-background-size: contain;
        -o-background-size: contain;
        background-size: contain;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
}
```

(N.B. As you are using Foundation's SASS version, you don't need all the prefixes, they are added for you when it builds)

So for medium + screens you get the two divs side by side with the image on the left, but for small you only get the first div, but now it has a background image.

Here's [a basic JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qpx3dcxk/1/), you'd need to tweak it to your image though.

Comment: Yes, I had implemented basically the same thing as you mentioned in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Try making the right column absolute and stick it to the right side, while giving it a lower z-index than the left column:

```
.snirky-snark-box{z-index:2;}

.frontpage-bg-image-wrapper{position:absolute; right:0; z-index:1;}
```

This should work. If it doesn't, please post a working snippet of your code (including CSS).